# JavaFX: Tooltip gets hidden by cursor

Tags: javafx, tooltip

I've been googling around trying to find a working solution, but I couldn't find any. Even using com.sun.glass.ui.Robot class.

This is a JavaFX Button with custom css and I want to move the tooltip down (on Y axis), because it's being hidden by the cursor.

Is there any workaround?

[image: tooltip hidden by cursor]

Comment: Provide MVCE. and actually you meant "Cursor gets hidden by tooltip"?

Comment: What do you mean "provide MVCE" ?

No I didn't meant that. Tooltip's position is so close under the cursor when it shows up and that's why it's being hidden by the cursor.

Comment: It is [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Despite your description, in the screenshot the tooltip is not covering the cursor, it seems.

Comment: @UlukBiy check again 

I updated the image with one taken from my smartphone

Comment: Search the SO to relocate the tooltip position, you can even use your own "tooltip" using popupcontrol etc.

Comment: @UlukBiy thank you
SO=?
popupcontrol=any relevant example/code?

Comment: SO=StackOverflow, Seach like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-2%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-8%5D+tooltip+location+is%3Aquestion) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-2%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-8%5D+popup+control+is%3Aquestion)